# Azure APIM developer portal - adding sign in : Oauth widget shows 2 buttons

Tags: azure-api-management

I used to see single button when I add widget "Sign in button:Oauth" i.e, Azure active directory.
But from past few days when i try to add widget "Sign in button : Oauth"  i see 2 buttons Azure active directory and Azure actice directory B2C. How do I disable the other button.

Comment: It seems you have selected  `Azure Active Directory B2C` in Identity provider type. You can refer to [Configure identity provider for developer portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c#configure-identity-provider-for-developer-portal) and [How to sign in with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad#legacy-developer-portal-how-to-sign-in-with-azure-ad)

Comment: Hello @Varun270489 Any update on this question does the provide answer resolve your issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As DeepDave-MT suggested , one of the workaround  we can think of for your problem is to disable the `Azure AD B2C tenant button` in our developer portal custom page.

We need to enable only Azure AD directory identity provider in API management service >Portal overview tab> Enable Azure AD

[image]

***NOTE: If you want only sign in button as Azure AD directory make sure that you have not enabled your Azure AD B2C in identity provider **  .

[image]

Here we can see two buttons in our Azure apim Developer portal ,if we enable both Azure AD and B2C in identity provider.

[image]

[image]

As we can see our button in our Developer Portal after adding and removing on Azure AD directory from identity provider:

For example:

**Before adding Azure Ad directory in identity provider**:

[image]

[image]

**After adding Azure AD directory in identity provider:**

[image]

For more information please refer this [Microsoft blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/authorize-developer-accounts-by-using-azure-active-directory-in/ba-p/1603185)

Comment: Awesome :) , Glad to be of help,  you can accept it as answer( click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you !!